# How can I extend qix color library to add custom manipulation functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, colors, module, extends

I am using the [qix color library](https://github.com/Qix-/color) and would like to be able define some specific custom manipulation functions to use in a theme.

I'm doing something like this:

```
import Color from 'color';

const primary = Color.rgb(34, 150, 168);

const getUltraLight = (color: Color): Color => {
  return color.mix(Color('white'), 0.9);
};

const getDark = (color: Color): Color => {
  return color.darken(0.3);
};
```

I can do this to get the hex value of the dark color I want:

```
const primaryDarkHex = getDark(primary).hex()
```

But what I would like to be able to is just call

```
primary.dark().hex()
```

so when I pass the color object as a prop to a react component I can use this

> What do I need to do in order to extend this imported module?

Answer (score 0):

You could make local edits, but they would all be overwritten if the dependencies are re-installed.  I would start by forking the project on Github, then make the necessary edits and either [publish your own package](https://zellwk.com/blog/publish-to-npm/), or install it as a dependency directly from [my own Github branch](https://medium.com/@jonchurch/use-github-branch-as-dependency-in-package-json-5eb609c81f1a).

Comment: I was hoping I could do something akin to : `class MyColor extends Color {...}`. Is there something like that I could use on a library import?

Comment: You could theoretically extend the prototype of the object this library exports, by importing ```Color``` and using ```Color.prototype.dark = function () { ... }```.  That may work for simple features, it doesn't sound like you're making major changes.  You just need to be sure you don't need any of the helper functionality that's not exported from the library.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried that and it kind of works. `Color.prototype.dark = function() { return this.darken(0.3) }` can then be called like this : `const darkHex = Color.rgb(34, 150, 168).dark().hex()`.

Comment: But how can I make this accessible in all my react components where I pass a color object as props?

Comment: You could create a file where you import ```Color```, modify the prototype and then export it again, and import the object from that file rather than the library in any component where it's needed, and then use it on any values, including props. **Edit:** Misunderstood, this solution should work

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have been trying to do this and it seems to work, but I'm running into typescript errors. I've added an answer so I can share the code in a more formatted way.

Comment: You are importing the modified version of ```Color``` as ```MyColor```, but calling ```Color```, which has not had its dark method defined.  Try ```console.log('Dark Test : ', MyColor.rgb(34, 150, 168).dark().hex())```

Comment: Thanks but that isn't it. This was just a typo, I've been trying it the other way and have amended the code here. Its technically works in that it produces the result I expect, but the typescript types are wrong and gives me the error I mentioned. I think it has something to do with the difference between `Color` type and `ColorConstructor` type.

Comment: Well I don't believe there are any Typescript types for that package, so you'd need to define your own, prevent them from being checked by the compiler, or ```//@ts-ignore``` the error.

Answer (score 0):

I have got this kind of working by importing the library, adding prototype functions and re-exporting :

```
import Color from 'color';

type ColorExt = Color & {
  dark: () => ColorExt;
};

Color.prototype.dark = function(): ColorExt {
  return this.darken(0.3) as ColorExt;
};

export default Color;
```

And then in another file I can do:

```
import MyColor from 'MyColor'
console.log('Dark Test : ', MyColor.rgb(34, 150, 168).dark().hex())
// Output -> Dark Test :  #186976
```

The only issue is I'm not sure how to treat this in *typescript*. I get this error when I call `dark()`:

**Property 'dark' does not exist on type 'Color'.**

Any ideas?